# How to ensure same float numbers on different systems?

Tags: c, floating-point, platform-independent

If I compile following c lines on windows and linux(ubuntu) I get different results. I would like to avoid. How can I do it?

```
 double a = DBL_EPSILON;
 double b = sqrt(a);
 printf("eps = %.20e\tsqrt(eps) = %.20e\n", a, b);
```

linux output:

```
eps = 2.22044604925031308085e-16        sqrt(eps) = 1.49011611938476562500e-08
```

windows output:

```
eps = 2.22044604925031310000e-016       sqrt(eps) = 1.49011611938476560000e-008
```

On linux tested with gcc and clang on 32-bit and 64-bit system same result.
On windows tested with gcc-mingw on 32-bit and visual-studio with 32-bit and 64-bit, also same results.

Comment: What is the underlying architecture of each system?

Comment: The `printf` implementations of the used c libraries differ. The Windows one prints only 17 significant digits or so, and fills with zeros if more are requested. glibc's prints the correctly rounded value.

Comment: but for me it doesn't seem that it's just an issue of printing, my numerical algorithm also return slightly different results. And I pointed this lines, since I assumed they are the source of differences.#

Comment: A `double` variable typically has [about 16 significant decimal digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation) of precision. It's pointless to print or compare digits past that.

Comment: Of course, but anyway they influence the result a numerical operation.

Comment: It's not platform independent, as Ubuntu Linux might be run on several different platforms, including [IBM system Z](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/mainframe-ubuntu-linux/9491).

Comment: @Blastfurnace: It is not pointless to print digits beyond 16. It may require 54 decimal digits to represent the exact value of a 64-bit IEEE 754 binary floating-point number, and one might want to see the exact value for a variety of reasons, such as transferring values to mathematical software capable of handling more precision or for debugging.

Comment: If you are not committed to C, Java has a strictfp mode in which the rounding is fixed across platforms and implementations, except for some of the functions such as Math.sin.

Comment: ... Nevermind the fact that *17* decimal digits are required to differentiate all double-precision values, not 16.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the example you give, it seems both programs have the **same** floating-point numbers. They just print them differently. The simplest solution around this particular issue is to write your own floating-point printing function. If you are not expecting too nice an output, you could use the function [here](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/10/29/A-portable-OCaml-function-to-print-floats) as pseudocode for writing your own in C. It is not correctly rounded, but it works for what it is intended for (that is, reproducible and readable outputs).

---

A deeper issue that your question hints you are encountering is floating-point **computations** giving different results on different platforms. This is a result of the C standard(s) not forcing compilers to implement the IEEE 754 floating-point standard exactly, specifically, allowing higher precision for intermediate results. And this relative leniency of the C standard(s) is caused at least in part by the historical x86 floating-point instructions making it expensive to implement the exact IEEE 754 semantics.

On Linux, assuming you are using GCC, try the `-msse2` compilation option. **EDIT: the OP commented that `-msse2 -mfpmath=sse` worked for him.**
This makes GCC generate modern SSE2 instructions that give the exact IEEE 754 floating-point semantics. If on Windows you are using GCC too, use the same option there.

If you are using Visual C: Visual C uses another trick to force the historical floating-point instructions to match IEEE 754 semantics: it tells the old 80-bit floating-point hardware to use only as many significand bits as IEEE 754 double-precision has. That gives an accurate simulation of double-precision numbers, except for a few corner cases that you will not be encountering. In this case it would help(*) if your program used only double-precision numbers (the C `double` type).

(*) The Visual C compiler could theoretically generate code that computes exact single-precision arithmetics by rounding each intermediate result from double to single precision, but this would be expensive and I doubt it does this.

Comment: I don't know if I would call overflow and underflow "corner case[s] that you will not be encountering"; they occur surprising often in real code.

Comment: @StephenCanon You caught me, I may not have been entirely honest: underflow and overflow can happen. My problem is that I do not have any solution to offer if they do happen, short of manually inserting in the program, everywhere they may happen, `intermediate_result = intermediate_result >= 0x1.0p+1024 ? inf : intermediate_result;`. And the story is even worse for underflow, for which I do not see any **portable** code to truncate the significand. If the programmer knows that he is using x87, then two calls to `ldexp()` should do it, but this will flush denormals to zero on IEEE 754 hardware

Comment: @StephenCanon Also, the “two calls to ldexp()` solution introduces double rounding.

Comment: Yes, it's an incredibly thorny issue; let's hope that the questioner is lucky enough to avoid it.

Comment: It seem that for gcc "-msse2 -mfpmath=sse" works for my issue. Thanks!