# Effect of hardware on simulation results

Tags: c++, operating-system, hardware, eigen, random-seed

I have a simulation code, written in C++ using standard libraries together with the Eigen library for linear algebra and matrices, and observed the following effect:

If I run it on my personal laptop, which is a Macbook with OS X, I get different results than what I get if I run it on my office PC with Ubutuntu OS.

The difference in the average result is approximately 20%.

I am sure that it is the same code, because both are running the updated version of the same repository.

The code is too complex to provide here, and has a lot of complicated mechanisms inside.

Remark: Running on the same device gives always a similar average, so my results are reproducible as long as they run on the same HW.

How should I interpret this? That my code is erroneous? Or such effects are normal?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit1:** I am using qmake but when I run the make command, this is an example line to compile my main.cpp on my Ubuntu PC:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -ICommon -INetwork -IEigen -I../../../Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/include -I../../../Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -Imocs -I../../../Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o objs/main.o main.cpp
```

The same line looks like the following on my OS X laptop:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++11  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -ICommon -INetwork -IEigen -I../../../opt/Qt5.14/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -Imocs -I../../../opt/Qt5.14/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/XXX/opt/Qt5.14/lib -o objs/main.o main.cpp
```

**Edit2:** I have an array of doubles which is calculated offline using Eigen libraries. Offline means here, the elements of the array have deterministic values, i.e., a lookup table. So, I have compared the content on both platforms, and the (printed) content is completely identical.

Comment: I am almost sure that the problem in different compiler flags.

Comment: What are you simulating?

Comment: Well, if you get the result 42 on one system and 50 on another system, it points towards errors in your code. That said, if you are using floating calculation, you can get different results but 20% off tells that you are doing it wrong. But without code, it's hard to help.

Comment: It is a research related simulation with control systems etc. In other words, it includes a lot of matrix multiplications and random noise. There is no interaction with the real world, if that is what you are asking. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @Gluttton how can I test this? Or make sure that they are the same?

Comment: @4386427 it is not a deterministic value. It is a long-term average of a system with man complicated mechanism inside. it is like 2.6 average instead of 2.2. And also, running on the same HW gives the same result, so it is not random.

Comment: Maybe you should take a closer look at the random noise (and other sources of randomness) since random number generation is implementation defined. How do you generate random numbers?

Comment: The answer to this Q may be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571073/how-to-ensure-same-float-numbers-on-different-systems

Comment: @OnurA, could you share your build script (make, cmake, etc)?

Comment: @churill I seed my random generators with: std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

Comment: @Gluttton see the edit

Comment: @OnurA, is the command line the same on both machines (Mac and Ubuntu)? Have you checked it?

Comment: It is not the same, but isn't this normal? I have given both in the original question

Comment: @OnurA yeah, that's completely normal, especially when calculating floating point numbers and having a very large difference in magnitude. GCC and Clang have very different optimizers, all it takes is for one operation to be swapped or one optimizer using some SIMD in cases and the other not.

Comment: I also don't see an -O2 in the clang case, so it looks like a debug build. Debug builds might also have differences to a Release build. If you want repeatably accurate results you need to use fixed-point calculations. Or be very careful to have operations be as numberically stable as possible, which seems hard with random numbers involved

Comment: @OnurA, I agree with PeterT that the most suspicious place is an optimization flag. I'd suggest putting the same level explicitly for both compilers (either -O0 or -O2) and then check results.

Comment: I did: i compiled with release flag, which added -O2. However, the result is still as before

Comment: @OnurA, so probably the problem is not related to compiler flags. As a next step, I'd suggest checking the Eigen version. And then analyze environment differences step by step.

Comment: Eigen version is the same, since it is using the sources in the repository. In other words,there isn't any system wide installation. To me, Edit2 hints at a random generator issue, would you agree?

Comment: Did you try seeding the PRNG with the same seed on both platforms? Eigen may give slightly different results if different vectorization options are enabled (like SSE, AVX, FMA) -- but usually not 20% difference (unless the algorithm itself is very unstable).

Comment: I think seeding alone wouldn't be a good test to see if it's the PRNG, use one run to generate a file with the random numbers and re-use those numbers on the other machine, that seems like a good way to check if it's the random numbers or not.

Comment: An additional info: I have tried my simulations on a 3rd PC, running ubuntu. The results among ubuntu devices are completely consistent. The results among different platforms are inconsistent, i.e., OS X vs. Ubuntu.